# ACL default permissions aren't working

Tags: permissions, rhel, acl

I'm going through [Sander Van Vugt](https://www.sandervanvugt.com/) course for RHCSA, and got stuck on ACL Lab assignment. Consider the following:

I have two following groups:

```
profs:x:1005:anna,audrey
students:x:1006:linda,lisa
```

I have directory /data/ with following subdirs:

```
[root@vudex ~]# ls -l /data/
total 0
drwxrws--T+ 2 anna profs    22 Feb 25 02:43 profs
drwxrws--T. 2 anna students  6 Feb 25 03:35 students
```

My goal is to make members of group "profs" read the content of /data/students directory. So, there is no ACL for /data/students at the moment, nor there are files.

```
[root@vudex ~]# getfacl /data/students/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: data/students/
# owner: anna
# group: students
# flags: -st
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

And

```
[root@vudex ~]# ls -l /data/students/
total 0
```

But when I set default ACL for the directory, user Audrey still cannot read /data/students content, thou being the member of "profs" group

```
[root@vudex ~]# setfacl -m d:g:profs:rx /data/students
[root@vudex ~]# getfacl /data/students
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: data/students
# owner: anna
# group: students
# flags: -st
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:profs:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

[root@vudex ~]# su - audrey 
[audrey@vudex ~]$ ls -l /data/students/
ls: cannot open directory '/data/students/': Permission denied
[audrey@vudex ~]$
```

But when I do setfacl command with `-R` flag, it works:

```
[root@vudex ~]# setfacl -Rm g:profs:rx /data/students
[root@vudex ~]# su - audrey
[audrey@vudex ~]$ ls -l /data/students/
total 0
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't default ACL be the choice, if directory does not contain any files or subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

did you have an execute permission on the /data/ directory prior that? I think it is an issue with the /data directory rather than the students

getfacl /data

Comment: [root@vudex ~]# getfacl /data/
    getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
    # file: data/
    # owner: root
    # group: root
    user::rwx
    group::r-x
    other::r-x

p.s. for some reason markdown isn't working for me

Comment: execute permission is in place for /data

Comment: I had the same problem, somehow default permissions does not work. With -R (--recursive) it works.